# VBA Function To Mirror Column

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to get excel to mirror columns, at the moment I'm using the code below, to update 2 cells based on each other, ideally I'd like to expand this so that any changes to a cell within D24:D100 affects the neighbouring cell within E24:E100 - can anyone help?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Address = "$D$24" Then
        Range("$E$24").Value = (Target.Value) * 1.11
    ElseIf Target.Address = "$E$24" Then
        Range("$D$24").Value = (Target.Value) / 1.11
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, please:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D24:E100")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Target.Column = 4 Then
            Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = Target.Value * 1.11
        ElseIf Target.Column = 5 Then
            Target.Offset(0, -1).Value = Target.Value / 1.11
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True
  End If
End Sub
```